# How can I create a scrollable region, that resizes with the browser, but also has fixed content region above and below the sizable area?

Tags: html, css

I apologize because though I'm sure this has been asked, I cannot find a solution after considerable searching.

I have a table that may have a lot of data loaded into it.  This table is housed within a content region that is part of a templated site, and within that content region there will be a title bar and a filter region above the table.  Below the table a series of buttons. The table needs to grow to fill the window but both the buttons at the bottom of the page, and he header/filter information at the top of the page must always remain in the browser window.

The sample code below is a general outline of the HTML I'm working with.  I have a title and filter divs that need to remain at the top of the content box, while the buttons at the bottom need to stay "anchored" at the bottom of the browser window.

The table (or it's containing div) need to grow to fill all of the space in the middle, and scrollbars need to appear when the content is to big for the window in the middle of the content region.

```html
<!-- site template content above -->
<div id="where the content is loaded for all pages">
  <div class="page-title"> <!-- Needs to stay at the top of the content box. SHOULD NOT vertically scroll out of view. -->
    Show a title, at the top of the page!
  </div>
  <div class="filters"> <!-- Should stay at the top, anchored below the Page Title div. -->
    <input type=text value="blah blah blah" />
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="fill-until-scrollable"> <!-- This needs to grow to fit (both x & y) as the browser window grows. -->
    <table> <!-- This table can have a lot of data. Assume it's height to be 100% of it's content, however, the fill-until-scrollable parent will need to have proper overflow/sizing CSS settings so that if the table data will be scrollable if it's to large for the window, without hiding the buttons below. -->
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="action-buttons"> <!-- This needs to be the full width of the page, anchored at the bottom of the browser window. -->
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- site template content below -->
```

I know this has to be a common need, but I can not find a way to do this.  Any simple examples would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably want to use flexbox, in a column direction. The top/bottom boxes should have `flex: 0 0 auto` to keep their size, and the middle block should have `flex: 1 1 auto;` along `overflow: auto`.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I avoided mentioning any of my attempts because I've found that on SO, when you mention one approach, answers will try to follow your lead some time, rather than giving you the best solution, which might take a different approach.  I've tried using flexbox settings but when I do, it ignores the overflow CSS and makes the table grow to the full height of the content.  If I get rid of the flexbox properties, I have to set a fixed height on the scroll region, which means it won't grow with the browser window.

Comment: The title, filters, and buttons have a fixed height?

Comment: @Roman yes, but some of the parts might be shown/hidden, depending on context.  They are fixed in size, though.

Comment: @RLH Sure but now we have to assume things about your project if you don't share your code… Anyway, see my answer. Should get you there.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen There's honestly nothing to assume.  Other than a bit of borders and coloring, I've stripped all placement CSS.  This is for all intents and purposes, a blank slate.  The difference between the sample I wrote and my legit code, is I stripped out real buttons/inputs and a table with it's header and column definitions using Angular mark-up. Not of that affects this request, so I just laid out a mocked up UI.

Comment: @RLH That's perfectly fine, but then you are expecting us to do the work if you don't show us what you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen (I'm only saying this in a friendly-debate manner. Please don't take this the wrong way.) But that's something I've never understood with the SO answering community. In the end, there is good answer regardless of if I've used flex properties or other placement CSS. Even with knowledge of my former attempts, it doesn't change the fact that the right answer is the right answer, and there's probably one, maybe two proper ways to do this. /cntd

Comment: I'm not opposed to writing code and showing what I've tried but when I've deleted, modified and rewritten this code countless times, there's not much to offer in a structured manner. It makes sense to me as a courtesy to present the problem, simply, and to leave the question as a blank slate without adding the additional baggage of my many chicken-scratched attempts at hacking something together from former, partial examples that I've found that have solve parts of the problem.

Comment: @RLH What you are saying is valid and I get what you mean. With that said, do understand why it is asked to present your attempts: it shows you've tried all you can, and you then came to SO because you needed help, and not because you were thinking "I wish I could do this and I don't want to search for it, someone can probably do it for me on SO." (I'm not saying you are in that category, of course). And this is a rule to which there will always be exceptions, so, you know, grain of salt and such. Hope my solution below will get you what you need!

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I appreciate that, and your point is valid. I'll consider that in the future. I really am that _other_ type of person where I hate to ask for help until I have exhausted all plausible attempts. In my case, I don't want to write a 4-5 page question, when a half a page will suffice and as I said, I consider that a courtesy to someone who may have the answer. But, I see your point! There are a lot of people, unfortunately, not willing to struggle before asking. It's also a courtesy to weed those questions out as well, for the sake of "normalized" information on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox will allow you to solve this so long as your container has a set height somewhere.

```css
.page {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-title,
.filters,
.action-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.fill-until-scrollable {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Just for the demo… delete these after */
.page { height: 40vh; /* I'm guessing 100vh in your case? */ }
.fill-until-scrollable table { display: block; height: 250vh; background: linear-gradient(00deg, grey, pink); }
```

```html
<!-- site template content above -->
<div class="page" id="where the content is loaded for all pages">
  <div class="page-title"> <!-- Needs to stay at the top of the content box. SHOULD NOT vertically scroll out of view. -->
    Show a title, at the top of the page!
  </div>
  <div class="filters"> <!-- Should stay at the top, anchored below the Page Title div. -->
    <input type=text value="blah blah blah" />
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="fill-until-scrollable"> <!-- This needs to grow to fit (both x & y) as the browser window grows. -->
    <table> <!-- This table can have a lot of data. Assume it's height to be 100% of it's content, however, the fill-until-scrollable parent will need to have proper overflow/sizing CSS settings so that if the table data will be scrollable if it's to large for the window, without hiding the buttons below. -->
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="action-buttons"> <!-- This needs to be the full width of the page, anchored at the bottom of the browser window. -->
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- site template content below -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if all elements except `.fill-until-scrollable` have known height.

```
<style>
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh
}
#container > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
.page-title {
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
.filters {
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.fill-until-scrollable{
  overflow: auto; 
  top: 200px;
  bottom: 100px
}
.action-buttons {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filter and button divs have fixed height, you can use calc() to set the height of the scrollable div like:

```
. fill-until-scrollable { height:calc(100% - 250px); overflow: auto;  }
```

Where 250px is the combined height of the other divs.

Comment: This _might_ work.  I have to support IE11 because it is the company standard. I know calc doesn't always work properly in IE11, so I'll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: calc() usually works ok in IE11 for simple operations, it starts to crap out with nested operations, transitions or dynamically generated content. Good Luck!